# Is it "a Ubuntu" or "an Ubuntu"?

Tags: 19.04

Silly question, let me know if this should be on Meta, but should you say "a Ubuntu (computer, LiveUSB, etc.)," pronouncing Ubuntu as "**You**-boon-too", or should you say "an Ubuntu (computer, LiveUSB, etc.)," pronouncing Ubuntu as "**Oo**-boon-too"?

Note: I just tagged it as 19.04 because no tags fit.

Comment: tl;dr for the duplicate: "an Ubuntu"

Comment: Ubuntu begins with a consonant sound, so we use 'a' before it not an.

Comment: @Community: The op is asking about whether to use "a" or "an", not about Ubuntu's pronunciation.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Community is a non-person moderator. In this case it looks like OP flagged and closed their own question.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron The official pronunciation of "Ubuntu" does *not* begin with a consonant sound. Please read the duplicate. Though I realize /jubʌntu/ is a common pronunciation, it's unofficial and arguably incorrect.

Comment: Ah, I see, **an** Uber cab is correct, **a** Uber cab is not.

Comment: @wjandrea I don't know how Community closed it. I didn't flag it.

Comment: @ScoopGracie Maybe you got a notification asking if the other question was the same as yours, and you clicked Yes?

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, I did. How did Community know to notify me?

Comment: @ScoopGracie Ah, so someone else flagged your question as a duplicate and you accepted it. That would do it.